# How do I use YCM after installing Anaconda?

Tags: python, vim, anaconda, youcompleteme

Getting error: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support.

It is installed with Python3. YCM was working great until installing Anaconda. To fix I tried adding this to my .vimrc:

```
let g:ycm_path_to_python_interpreter = '/usr/bin/python'
```

I have also referred to the YCM FAQ and tried adding this to my .ycm_extra_conf.py:

```
def Settings(**kwargs):
  return {
    'interpreter_path': '/path/to/anaconda/python'
  }
```

However nothing has removed or changed the error.

I have recompiled with anaconda python and then redid it with normal python when that didn't work either. It seems from others who asked this question it does need to be compiled with non-anaconda python.

I have seen suggestions to remove the anaconda path from .bash_profile but doesn't that defeat the purpose of having Anaconda?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

Solved the problem by commenting out the Anaconda path in my .bash_profile. 'which' python still points to Anaconda python, but YCM compiles and works again.

No idea why this approach works, but it does.

Comment: Could you post the output of `vim --version`?

Comment: NVIM v0.2.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5

Comment: I also get compilation information but am not sure if that is of interest, and is too long to comment here. If it will be helpful I will add it to the question, or put it in answers below.

Comment: The compilation information ist the interesting part (; Please add it to your question

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper Thank you for trying to help! However, I've solved the problem and have now updated the question with the solution. Unclear on why this solution works though.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept your answer then. (:

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper Comment out the Anaconda path in  .bash_profile not work for me, still get error: `YouCompleteMe unavailable: /home/roach/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyByteArray_Type`.

Comment: There is an issue at their github site: https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2427

If this doesn't help you, you should open your own question, where we can look deeper into this.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't compile Youcompleteme successfully, which really made me confused.
Finally I found that is caused by Anaconda. So I used the default version python to recompile it again.

```
$ /usr/bin/python ~/.vim/bundle/Youcompleteme/install.py
```

It works perfectly.